# Teradata DB date insertion error using Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, date, insert, teradata

We are using Hibernate to insert data from our JAVA app to Teradata database.
Now, there is a date column in table,so we just pass the new Data() in that and trying to save it. But it is giving us the below error:

```
Caused by: com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.util.JDBCException: [Teradata Database] [TeraJDBC 14.00.00.13] [Error 5404] [SQLState HY000] Datetime field overflow.
    at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.util.ErrorFactory.makeDatabaseSQLException(ErrorFactory.java:307)
    at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.statemachine.ReceiveInitSubState.action(ReceiveInitSubState.java:102)
    at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.statemachine.StatementReceiveState.subStateMachine(StatementReceiveState.java:302)
```

For reference:

My enitiy class:

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "EDW_CREATE_DTM")    
    public Date getEdwCreateDtm() {
        return edwCreateDtm;
    }
```

In my service class... setting the value before insert:

```
someObject.setEdwCreateDtm(new Date());
```

Is there any specific way for inserting date to teradata ??

Any pointers on this would really help.

Answer (score 0):

Is your target column defined as a TIMESTAMP or DATE?

If it is defined as a TIMESTAMP are you attempting to insert a time precision that is greater than the precision of your TIMESTAMP data type? For example, if the column is defined as TIMESTAMP(0) and you attempt to insert '2012-05-15 14:25:46.125' you may receive an overflow error. Your column would need to be defined as TIMESTAMP(3).

If it is defined as a DATE then the TIME portion of your TIMESTAMP is not supported. DATE data types in Teradata are 'yyyy-mm-dd' or comparable values.